Picard group of the category of numerical motives
Is anything known about the Picard group of $Chow_{Num}(k, \mathbb{F}_{p})$ (numerical Chow motives with $\mathbb{F}_{p}-$coefficients)?
Perhaps the Picard groups of some other categories of pure motives have been calculated?
Thanks in advance.
